# How to get the specific content in Python with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm new to Python and I'm coding a little scraper in Python with BeautifulSoup, in order to get the address from the webpage. I have attached the picture of it 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/272TX.png)

```
    </div>
    </div>
    <div data-integration-name="redux-container" data-payload='{"name":"LocationsMapList","props":{"locations":[{"id":17305,"company_id":106906,"description":"","city":"New York","country":"United States","address":"5 Crosby St  3rd Floor","state":"New York","region":"","latitude":40.719753,"longitude":-74.0001954,"hq":true,"created_at":"2015-01-19T01:32:16.317Z","updated_at":"2016-05-05T07:57:19.282Z","zip_code":"10013","country_code":"US","full_address":"5 Crosby St  3rd Floor, New York, 10013, New York, USA","dirty":false,"to_params":"new-york-us"}]},"storeName":null}' data-rwr-element="true">
```

I got the full content by using BeautifulSoup but I don't know how to extract the content of the "full_address". I saw it's in "div" but I don't know what to do next.

`links = soup.find_all('div')`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: (please add your code as text instead of a picture)

Comment: I added it. Thanks!

Comment: The `'data-payload'` attribute is json, so use `json.loads`

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the nomenclature of html - [W3C Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp).  [The BeautifulSoup docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects) have some good fundamentals - If you read through it keeping your problem in mind, you may start to see solutions.

Comment: You may also want to spend some time working your way through [the Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get an idea of the tools available to you.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

data = '''
</div>
    </div>
    <div data-integration-name="redux-container" data-payload='{"name":"LocationsMapList","props":{"locations":[{"id":17305,"company_id":106906,"description":"","city":"New York","country":"United States","address":"5 Crosby St  3rd Floor","state":"New York","region":"","latitude":40.719753,"longitude":-74.0001954,"hq":true,"created_at":"2015-01-19T01:32:16.317Z","updated_at":"2016-05-05T07:57:19.282Z","zip_code":"10013","country_code":"US","full_address":"5 Crosby St  3rd Floor, New York, 10013, New York, USA","dirty":false,"to_params":"new-york-us"}]},"storeName":null}' data-rwr-element="true">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-integration-name':'redux-container'}):
    info = json.loads(i.get('data-payload'))
    for i in info['props']['locations']:
        print i['address']
```

Comment: It says: KeyError: 'locations'

Comment: @Laura for my solution to work I assume that the data you are trying to parse are exactly the same as those in your post. Are your data the same  cause from the error you posted it seems that 'locations' doesn't exist in your data ? Also to view the keys you can do `print i.keys()`

Comment: Maybe limit it to `div`'s that have `data-integration-name="redux-container" ` attribute.

Comment: @Laura  The answer was more to demonstrate the use of `json` and how can be used to parse this kind of data. Now you should be able to make some research and apply it to different data too. Also as mentioned in the comments section you should read very carefully the [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) docs

Comment: @coder, it still shows the same error. But thanks very much! I will go back and read bs4 documentation.